# MASM - Differences between procedures and macros

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I was wondering what are the differences between `macros` and `procedures` in MASM ?

Is there a difference with what the program will do or how the assembler will assemble my code, if I call a `macro` instead of a `procedure` that do the exact same thing ?

If no, I might want to understand why do `macros` exist ?

Thanks.

Comment: Macros exist to make inlining easy (e.g. with different choices of registers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A macro is just text replacement. So any time you "call" a macro, that call will be replaced by the full contents of the macro at compile-time. When you call a procedure, there's typically only one instance of that procedure, so you'll branch to a different place in the program.

Consider the following example:

```
.586
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

.code

; Multiply the argument by 3/2
Mul3_2 MACRO reg
    lea reg,[reg + reg*2]
    shr reg,1
ENDM

; Multiply the argument by 3/2 and return in eax
Mul3_2Proc PROC arg:DWORD
    mov eax,[arg]
    lea eax,[eax + eax*2]
    shr eax,1
    ret
Mul3_2Proc ENDP

main PROC
    Mul3_2 eax
    Mul3_2 ebx

    invoke Mul3_2Proc,eax    ; Equivalent to push eax / call Mul3_2Proc
    invoke Mul3_2Proc,ebx   
main ENDP

END main
```

If we let MASM's preprocessor expand our macro we get this:

```
.586
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

.code

; Multiply the argument by 3/2 and return in eax
Mul3_2Proc PROC arg:DWORD
    mov eax,[arg]
    lea eax,[eax + eax*2]
    shr eax,1
    ret
Mul3_2Proc ENDP

main PROC
    lea eax,[eax + eax*2]
    shr eax,1
    lea ebx,[ebx + ebx*2]
    shr ebx,1

    invoke Mul3_2Proc,eax    ; Equivalent to push eax / call Mul3_2Proc
    invoke Mul3_2Proc,ebx
main ENDP

END main
```

As you can see, at the two places where we used the `Mul3_2` macro, the contents of that macro has been inserted, with `reg` replaced by whatever we passed as the argument to the macro. The macro itself no longer exists in our code, because it has served its purpose.

On the other hand, the two occurrences where we invoked the `Mul3_2Proc` procedure remain unchanged. At runtime there will be a jump (`call`) from each of those places to `Mul3_2Proc`, which in turn will `ret`urn back to the call site when it is done.